# Visual Studio 2008 search box is hiding when using remote desktop on single monitor

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, search, monitor, remote-desktop

I work on dual monitors at work.  However, if I leave work with Visual Studio 2008 open and my last search had the search box (quick find or Ctrl+F box) on the right monitor, and log in from home on a single monitor using remote desktop, I'm unable to see the search box.  I can type and find stuff, but I can't use the advanced options in that search dialog.  I tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio, but that didn't work.  Normally Alt+spacebar + arrow works, but that only works for Windows parent windows, not child windows.  I am unable to switch monitors since I only have one monitor at home.  I'm also unable to change the resolution to anything larger on this single monitor computer--I'm at the largest.  I am using the shift+ctrl+f right now, but I can't toggle between "Current Document" or "Current Project", etc..  Any ideas on how I can move that search box to the monitor I'm currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to solve this within Windows.  But.... When at work (on two monitors), keep the search box on the left monitor all the time, even if you prefer to have Visual Studio on the right screen.  When you log into Windows with one screen, the search box will be on the left screen.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW on VS2010 it **is** possible to move the Find window using the following sequence:

```
Ctrl+Shift+F
Alt+Space
M
Hold down left arrow
Enter
```

However I do sympathise with you, I use 2 monitors at work and that window has a mind of its own.
I don't think it's ever closed and reopened in the same location.

Comment: Sweet.  I'll give this a shot!  We're eventually moving to VS2010 (hopefully soon)